# Definability of $j:V\to M$ is an elementary embedding

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I was looking at Woodin's chapter in the book *Infinity: New Research Frontiers* and I'm confused by some of his remarks regarding class-sized elementary embeddings. The following is taken from the book:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. Why is there a bound on the complexity of the defining formulas?
2. I don't see why the two bulleted items are equivalent. For the forward direction, fix an ordinal $\alpha$ and $a\in V_\alpha$, then by the absoluteness of satisfaction and because $\phi$ is $\Delta_0$-definable,

$$ V_\alpha\models \phi[a]\iff V\models (V_\alpha\models \phi[a]) \iff M\models (j(V_\alpha)\models \phi [j(a)]) \\ \iff  j(V_\alpha)\models \phi[j(a)] $$

I get stuck on the backwards direction. I'm sure it's some kind of reflection argument, but the details escape me. Given a formula $\phi$ and $a\in V$, let $\alpha>rk(a)$ reflect $\phi$, i.e. $V_\alpha \preceq_\phi V$. Then
$$
V\models \phi[a] \iff V_\alpha\models \phi[a] \iff j(V_\alpha)\models \phi[j(a)]
$$

If $M\models ZFC$, then I can argue that $M\models V_\alpha\preceq_\phi V$ so that $V_\alpha^M\preceq_\phi M$, and so it suffices to show that $V_\alpha^M=j(V_\alpha)$ for every ordinal $\alpha$, but I'm not sure how to do that (another reflection argument?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for your comment. Unless I'm misunderstanding things, the elementarity of $j$ is exactly what we're trying to prove. I can say thinks like $V_\alpha \models \sigma(x,y)\iff j(V_\alpha)\models \sigma(j(x),j(y))$, but I don't see how to relate truth in $j(V_\alpha)$ to truth in $M$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misparsed things.

Comment: Yes, you are going to use Reflection as hard as humanly possible.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not sure what you're suggesting, would you mind saying a bit more?